# curious '-' and space appearing when on live site

Tags: css, symfony, templates, twig

It's strange on my local ubuntu apache server, in development this does not show, when I upload to the centos apache server, admin via plesk I get this annoying dash '-' and a white space above the top image of the page. this is the view source you can see the - before head.  Both twig templates are the same. wonder if the server is adding something. it's weird and irritating and make the site look rubbish, sigh

```
 -  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Concert Flow - Find Live Music You'll Love</title>
<!-- Mobile viewport optimized: h5bp.com/viewport -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<!-- Style Sheet-->

<!-- favicon -->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5.js"></script>             
<![endif]-->
<!-- Color Scheme -->



                 </head>
```

Comment: This is your site I take it: http://concertflow.com/ - I am looking at the raw page source, there is no `<html>` tag anywhere in the output. And if you look at the rendered output in the Firefox inspector, it's spitting a lot of  `<head>` elements out in the body itself. So if you have a master layout file, I'd start by making sure everything is present and correct there. Are you using Twig's template caching, or have you cleared the cache for your prod environment; i.e: `app/console cache:clear --env=prod`?

Comment: Hi Darragh, Yes that's the site, you're right it didn't have <html> thanks for spotting that.  I don't have a master layout at present.  I added <html> cleared cache still have the dash. surely I would get this locally as well, which I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found, it was nothing to do with the HTML template.  The minus character had accidently been added to app.dev before the  tag, if any stray characters are added in there they will appear on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding your code not the page source. I think there should be some problem with your opening `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload all relevant files that output HTML.
2. Ensure you don't have any third party software causing this sort of nonsense.
3. Output underscores in various parts of your code, upload those HTML output files and then that will give you a better idea of where the culprit is located.

In example if the output is "__-_" then you look after the second underscore. If there is still a lot of code being output between the second and third (in this example) then erase the first two and then output more underscores.

Make sure that the test underscore code is the *exact same code* so you can easily hunt them down and remove them.

You're lucky this is happening on an early Sunday morning when traffic is traditionally much slower.

Also add a `doctype`, it's not 1996 any more.